# How to fix Rcmdr masking base R error code

Tags: r

Rcmdr is masking error code in Base R. Error message when loading Rcmdr:

"Attaching package: 'Rcmdr'
The following object is masked from 'package:base':
errorCondition"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn’t an error, it’s a *warning*. You can (in this case) safely ignore it. You can also disable it by passing `warn.conflicts = FALSE` to `library`:

```
library(Rcmdr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
```

You’ll get such a warning whenever attaching a package that is exporting the same names as some other, already attached package. Notably, ‘dplyr’ also causes this warning because it overrides (at the time of writing) four functions from ‘base’ and two from ‘stats’.